# HTML: Footer width issue

Tags: html, css, width, footer

my webpage is totally fine, I just have one problem:
My webpage contains a "footer", but I want to show it every time in a small bar at the bottom of my page (not just if I scroll down to the end of my page). I set a z-index to 1 (so its in front of all the other stuff) and also gave it a background color. But for some reason it is just in the bottom left hand corner and very small, I tried to put the width to 100%, but for some reason that didn't change something. here my html code:

```css
.footer-links{
  z-index: 1; 
}

.footer-links ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none; 
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-links ul li a{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Footer -->
<div class="footer-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="text3.html">text3</a></li>
    <li><a href="text2.html">text2</a></li>
    <li><a href="text1.html">text1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `width` and the `background-color`in the `.footer-links ul` and set the left boundary on `.footer-links`

```css
.footer-links{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0px;
  left:0;
}

.footer-links ul{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none; 
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-links ul li a{
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="text3.html">text3</a></li>
    <li><a href="text2.html">text2</a></li>
    <li><a href="text1.html">text1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a fix footer, You can use:

**For your footer:**

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**For your body:**

```
body {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make a few adjustments to your CSS as there is a lot of unnecessary formatting going on. Here's my suggestion:

```css
.footer-links{
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-links ul{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none; 
}

.footer-links ul li a{
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="text3.html">text3</a></li>
    <li><a href="text2.html">text2</a></li>
    <li><a href="text1.html">text1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4waLb0qu/

HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
<p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p><p>!</p>
<div class="footer-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="text3.html">text3</a></li>
    <li><a href="text2.html">text2</a></li>
    <li><a href="text1.html">text1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-links{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-links ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-links ul li a{
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}
```